Why doesn't my outlet switch work after outlet replacement?
I was replacing old outlets with 120v 15amp three prong outlets. The house was built in the 1920s and still has the old tube wiring randomly over the house.
Current Situation:
The light switch is not able to control outlets 5 and 6.
Before I changed all outlets 5 & 6 had lights plugged into the top outlet to where if I walked out the room I would hit the switch in the off position the lights would shut off.
After installed the new outlets I have lost that ability. I did not change the way it was wired so it's technically the original wiring.
I should note that 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 have double wiring of the red and black 14/2 wire. I tried fusing with outlet six and tripped the breaker twice with no luck.
Let me know your thoughts on the diagram and what changes I should make.


did you break off the tabs between the terminalls to the red and black wires?

Please edit the question to clarify what you mean by "double wiring".  I think you mean you have a single 14/3 cable with Red, Black, White.  Perhaps also a green or bare wire.  Please clarify.   Also in the question explain the relevance of any knob and tube wiring to this problem.  If it's all 14/3 cable, even if you have some knob and tube elsewhere, if it's not relevant here so please keep it simple.

Is the switch supposed to control all 6 outlets?

Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Then revise to be more clear and concise.

To control the upper part of outlet 5 and 6 by switch you must first break of the bridge between the upper and lower screws on the hot (brass) side. Leave the neutral side intact.

Then remove the hot wire (red in your depiction) between outlets 4 and 5. (as shown in white over the red.)
If your outlets 1 through 4 all have the bridges between upper and lower screws intact there is no need for any of red wires in your drawing.
Run the switched hot from the switch to the upper brass screw of outlet 6 then to upper brass screw of outlet 5. (Yellow in the pic)  This will make the upper part of outlets 5 and 6  switched hot. The lower parts will always be hot.  The neutrals will stay the same as you have them.
Do not put 2 wires on one screw. make a "pigtail" in box 6 to continue the switched wire to outlet 5.

